# Java Connection SQL isValid() not being recognized

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I keep getting the error "The method isValid(int) is undefined for the type Connection"

I am currently using eclipse galileo, have JRE and JDK 6, and have all appropriate .jar files available.

i use the mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar and bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar

and the weirdest part is another person sharing same code has no problem and does not see this error.

Comment: is the code you both are using , exactly Identical? Can you post the relevant code if its not too big?

Answer (score 0):

There are several `Connection` classes in different libraries, make sure that you are importing the right one (`java.sql.Connection`). Also, check if you imported the jars in your build path properly.

`isValid(int)` is indeed a method for `java.sql.Connection` and you shouldn't get this error if you're using the right `Connection` class.

Answer (score 0):

This method of Connection class is driver dependent and does not work well with old drivers instead made my own isValid() implementation , which works well

```
private static boolean isValid(Connection conn){
    if(CommonUtils.isNotNull(conn)){
        try(
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select sysdate mydate from dual");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            ){
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.catching(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;        
}
```